# How to reverse a SoundSample array?

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I have to reverse the order of an array called myWordArray that plays from a thisisatest.wav file. It should play "test a is this" instead of "this is a test."

```
public void playReverseOrder(int pause) throws InterruptedException {
        Sound orig = new Sound();
        int length = myWordArray.length; 

        for (int i = 0, source = length - 1; i < length && source > 0; i++, source--) {
            myWordArray[i].setSampleValueAt(i, orig.getSampleValueAt(source));
            myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
            Thread.sleep(pause);
        }

    }
```

My logic is that I create a new sound, then use the length to increment the index i forward as the original source decrements. It plays forward, however I cannot get the words to reverse. I've thought of retrieving the samples of the myWordArray within new Sound (myWordArray.getSamples()); however that does not work, and I would try to access the file within the parameters, but we select the file manually within the test harness.

Comment: How about you loop backward over the array instead of reversing it?

Comment: Are you expecting `test a is this`? or  `test is a this`?

Comment: Sorry, I messed that up. I'm expecting "test a is this."

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you meant `test a is this`. This is a harder problem and discussed below. If you want to make it sound like `tset a si siht`, you can simply arrange the content of the array in reverse order. Please note that, this sound wont be intelligible.

> ```
>        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
>        Thread.sleep(pause);
> ```

In your code, I guess you don't need this.

If you are interested in `test a is this`, the process would be something like this:

1. Find number of words in the sound file, *requires little knowledge of audio signal processing*
2. Mark their boundaries
3. Now, half of the work is done. Only remaining part is playing back the sounds of words in reverse order.
4. Create another `Sound`, fill the samples array with all segmented pieces of words, but in *reverse* order. Done.